Tasks are "submitted to server"... but never "running on server"?
Yesterday afternoon, I submit a few tasks to Google Earth Engine and they ran just fine.
Yesterday night, I submitted a few more. This morning, they look like there has been no progress done - they still show as "submitted to server", not "running on server", and still shows as if it's been running for less than one minute.
I don't think it's an issue with my script because I submit a test job this morning and it shows the same issue.


I made another project, had the same issue. Made another account, and that one runs just fine! But I'd like to know what was the issue with my former account that nothing could be exported from it.

following this, can i turn off my computer if its still submitted on server

yes - once it's submitted, it's on the server, and you're good.

GEE only allows a few tasks per user to run at the same time. https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/processing_environments#:~:text=*%20and%20ee.-,batch.,number%20of%20concurrently%20running%20tasks.
It might be that these are just pending. Do you have any tasks that are actually running?

No, nothing is running. I even cancelled all tasks and ran another test one, and the same issue is happening. I created a new project and started a simple task there, also nothing. Wondering if it's something with my account - could I have run out of credits or something? My next try is to make an entirely new GEE account.

That's it - a new account runs just fine. I'm editing my question.

Good that it worked out! It's not always easy to set up a new account
